# How to initialize ArrayAdapter / Listview + check on click

Tags: android, listview

Why is my `ArrayAdapter` `null`? It enter on exception and when I look the message, it gave me `null`. I can't initialize this array. I test my `string[]` and it's not `null`. I see all the file names from my `mImageFilenames`.

```
private void PopulateListView() {

        mPrivateRootDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "");
        Toast.makeText(this, mPrivateRootDir + " <--mPrivateRootDir||",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get the files/images subdirectory;

        mImagesDir = new File(mPrivateRootDir, "MyPdf");
        Toast.makeText(this, mImagesDir + "<--mImagesDir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();


        // Get the files in the images subdirectory
        mImageFiles = mImagesDir.listFiles();
        Toast.makeText(this, mImageFiles[0] + "<--mImageFiles||",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     // Set up ListView
        listViewSelectFile = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewSelectFiles);
        // listViewSelectStudent = (ListView)
        // findViewById(R.id.listviewSelectStudent);

        /*
         * Display the file names in the ListView mFileListView. Back the
         * ListView with the array mImageFilenames, which you can create by
         * iterating through mImageFiles and calling File.getAbsolutePath() for
         * each File
         */

        mImageFilenames = new String[mImageFiles.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mImageFilenames.length; ++i) {
            mImageFilenames[i] = mImageFiles[i].getName();
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    mImageFilenames[i] + "<-- mImageFilenames[i]" + " FOR",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        try {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.listview, mImageFilenames);

            listViewSelectFile.setAdapter(adapter);
            // listViewSelectStudent.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ArrayAdapter Error :" + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

**EDIT**

screen3 xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewSelectFiles"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_view_rows xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listviewSendFile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Send_Files"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception? Is it the first line of the try block or the second?

Comment: On second line i get exception , on  R.layout.list_view_rows  contain a textview on name :listviewSendFile

Comment: Did you check my answer? If it contains a TextView, then you need to pass its id instead of the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the problem

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.listview, mImageFilenames);
```

You need to pass the id of a `TextView` in the parameters not a listview. Change it to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.someTextView, mImageFilenames);
```

The `TextView` should be present in `list_view_rows.xml`

**EDIT**

Since you want a simple `ListView`, you need to initialize it and the ArrayAdapter in the `onCreate()` of the activity. Just return the list's value from the populate method.
This is how you would set an adapter for a `ListView`

```
onCreate()
{    
...
    values = populateListView(); //just make the method return an array or ArrayList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
..
}
```

Comment: in R.layout i need to have the listview , and in R.id. ( i need to have a textview ) right ? i try like this it doesn't work

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewSelectFiles"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: No. In R.layout, it is the layout of one row of your ListView. Maybe a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. And the TextView should be present in that layout file.

Comment: I saw the xml. That's not how it should be. Read my previous comment

Comment: i maked again these xml and i posted them in edit , if they are ok tell help me to complete arrayAdapter parameters

Comment: Ok tell me one thing, do you want to show just simple text in the list or more views like images etc?

Comment: i want to show 2 list view parallel ( only text contain both)

Comment: In the same activity? Either way, that is something you can deal with later. For a simple text list, I'll just update my answer.

Comment: Did you call setContentView(layout.xml) in the onCreate()??

Comment: when i click on a item from listview i wanted to be checked , i put this it's not checking : lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

Comment: What do you mean by checked? Please edit your question for more queries

Comment: when i press one of my item from listview  that item set as checked

Comment: In that case, you should put a checkbox in your row layout. For that you need to design listview with custom adapter. http://developerandro.blogspot.in/2013/09/listview-with-checkbox-android-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this：

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view_rows,             mImageFilenames);
```

Comment: R.layout.list_view_rows what shoult contain ? the listview ?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter adapter_name = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item,ArrayList_name);
//the format of array adapter should look like this 
 ArrayAdapter adapter_name  = ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId, T[] objects);
//simple_list_item is list view xml file
//ArrayList_name is list that is to be processed in list view

Comment: Can you add some description? It would be usefull for users to understand your code faster